# Running two tomcat on a single port

Tags: apache, tomcat, multiple-instances

Any one have an idea to share running multiple tomcats on single machine with same port 8080

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to run 2 websites on mcahine with same port 8080. If I shutdown one server that should not affect the other server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to set up a single web server (such as Apache, but your choice) on port 8080, which forwards requests based on URL to the appropriate Tomcat instance running on a different port, such as 8081 or 8082.

Comment: I want both instance to run on 8080. Any way to do this?

Comment: Alzzz, can you please re-read what Greg has proposed? Are you sure you understand this?

Comment: Greg Hewgill: if we run on 8081 or 8081 we need to mention like http://IPADDRESS:81/ to access the website. Where in the default is http://IPADDRESS . I want both my sites on 8080 even though as you saying I can do it my running multiple instances.

Comment: @Alzzz: I think you are somewhat confused about ports and how they work. Port 8080 is *not* the same as port 80. The standard HTTP port is 80 (not 8080), and any other port requires that the user use the `:XX` port specifier in the URL. So running something on port 8080 would require that the user use `http://address:8080` to connect to it. Also, only *one* process can listen on any given port at one time. So you cannot run two instances of Tomcat listening on the same port on the same machine, unless you use a third server to proxy the requests to the correct instance of Tomcat.

Comment: @Alzzz: It is possible. I have described how. I don't think you have understood what I have said, though.

Comment: @Gereg you are saying :xx port should be specified in the url? How I tell all the users across the world to specify my port :xx in the url?

Comment: @Alzzz: You definitely have not understood what I have said. Run Apache (or whatever) on port 80. Run Tomcat A on port 8081, run Tomcat B on port 8082. Set up Apache to forward requests to Tomcat A or Tomcat B on the local machine depending on the URL.

Comment: @Greg "Set up Apache to forward requests to Tomcat A or Tomcat B on the local machine depending on the URL"- in which folder I could do this setup? Do you have any online resource where in I could read this?

Comment: @Alzzz: The key words to look for in Google are "apache reverse proxy". If you have further questions about this, please create a new question on http://serverfault.com (this is technically off topic for Stack Overflow). Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, you can not run two different web servers at same port.

Comment: one server with multiple tomcat instances on same port. Any way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this.. Leave apart tomcat, this won't work with any combination of servers. Explain your requirements better

Comment: I want to run 2 websites on mcahine with same port 8080. If I shutdown one server that should not affect the other server.

Comment: You may want to learn about virtual hosts setup.  This is how multiple domains are setup on a single server.  Basically, when a client browser tries to access a domain setup on a shared server, it sends three pieces on information to identify the target document. 1.> IP address of the server (using this the server is identified, 2.> Port of the server (using this the running application is identified, like tomcat) and 3.> Domain name, using this the website instance is identified.  Setting up this configuration is called Virtual Hosts configuration.  Look into it

Comment: And remmember that you "access" the two different sites by specifying different domain names.  If you are doing this setup on a local machine (or on a network that doesn't have a DNS setup), you can use hosts file to setup your domain to IP mapping.

Comment: If you set up virtual host for this-For maintenance a website if I want shutdown my server, that would affect my other website which is running on the same machine. So setting virtual hosts will not meet my requirement.

Comment: this is always the problem with shared servers :)

Comment: thats true. But we should come across.

Answer (score -1):

To or more instance of an application can be listening on the same port, as far the server supports portsharing ! Any request to this adr:port will be distributed among this different instances.